# Help with SELECT statement

Tags: sql, mysql

First, I know that's a terribly vague title -- my knowledge of SQL is so weak that I don't really know the particulars of what I'm asking, so please bear with me.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
| gameid | team1     | team2    | score1 | score2 |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
|      1 | New York  | Boston   |      1 |      2 |
|      2 | New York  | Boston   |      2 |      0 |
|      3 | Baltimore | New York |      3 |      1 |
|      4 | Boston    | New York |      3 |      0 |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Where gameid is a unique identifier, score1 corresponds to the score for team1, etc.

What I need is a query that will produce a summation of wins and losses for a given team against all opponents. Using New York for example, the query would create the following table:

```
+-----------+------+--------+
| team      | wins | losses |
+-----------+------+--------+
| Baltimore |    0 |      1 |
| Boston    |    1 |      2 |
+-----------+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have access to a SQL box right now (so this may be syntax-weak) and I'm not a huge fan of the db structure but this ought to get you going:

```
SELECT team, SUM(win) AS wins, SUM(loss) AS losses
FROM
 (SELECT team1 AS team, 
   CASE WHEN score1>score2 THEN 1 END AS win, 
   CASE WHEN score2>score1 THEN 1 END AS loss
  FROM YourTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT team2 AS team, 
   CASE WHEN score2>score1 THEN 1 END AS win, 
   CASE WHEN score1>score2 THEN 1 END AS loss
  FROM YourTable)
GROUP BY team
```

Also, this ignores ties.

**Note:** I made this CW--please update if you can improve it

Comment: your closing paren is in the wrong place. I'm surprised we came up with the exact same solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but the query is going to come out to be very complicated.  If possible, perhaps you could reorganize your schema to encode some more information into it.  For instance, rather than `team1` and `team2`, you could have `winning_team` and `losing_team`; similiarly, using `winning_score` and `losing_score`  you wouldn't have to check which score corresponded with which team.  Then you could do a `GROUP BY` on `losing_team` to get all the wins for a particular team against each other team, and one on `winning_team` to get the losses (and avoid using score at all in this particular query).

Comment: Agreed. Something that better represents a `game` or a win/lose log (e.g. 1 row per team per game) would make this easier

Comment: So the consensus is that my table structure is crap, got it. Like I said, db management isn't really my thing, this is a bit of learning exercise for me. But I have several very large tables -- would it make good sense to have a 'results' table that is a derivative of the 'games' table?

@Michael Haren -- essentially doubling the size of the table I have now?

Comment: How many games are we talking about (100 1000 10000...)? In a sense, this is analagous to double entry book keeping--for one team to win, another must lose. You could record all these as transactions with a ledger style DB

Comment: The 'games' table has ~150,000 rows now -- it'll probably expand to ~250,000 over time.

Comment: If you normalize it a bit to have a FK reference for each team instead of copying the team name string each time, and add a "winner" column as @pixeline suggested (possibly computed/calculated/formula--whatever mysql calls them), I think you can keep much the same structure with the same number of rows, but a much smaller (byte-wise) table.

Answer (score 1):

ditto to @David's comments, This would be mist easier if your table structure was more normailized, but, with the schema as it is, Try this SQL

```
  Select T.Team,
     Sum(Case When S1.Score1 > S1.Score2 Or 
                   S2.Score2 > S2.Score1 Then 1 Else 0 End) Wins,
     Sum(Case When S1.Score1 < S1.Score2 Or 
                   S2.Score2 < S2.Score1 Then 1 Else 0 End Losses,
     Sum(Case When S1.Score1 = S1.Score2 Or 
                   S2.Score2 = S2.Score1 Then 1 Else 0 End Ties     
   (Select Distinct team1 team from Table
    Union Select Distinct team2 team from Table) T
      Left Join Table S1
         On S1.Team1 = T.Team
      Left Join Table S2
         On S2.Team2 = T.Team
  Group By T.Team
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT 
     team
    ,sum(wins) as wins
    ,sum(losses) as losses
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
         team1 as team
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN score1 > score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wins
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN score1 < score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as losses
    FROM
        myTable
    GROUP BY
        team1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
         team2 as team
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN score2 > score1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as wins
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN score2 < score1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as losses
    FROM
        myTable
    GROUP BY
        team2 
    ) a
GROUP BY
team
```